# Wear App and with custom build type with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I have an app where I'd like to add an Android Wear app extension. The main app has three build types (debug, beta and release). Beta builds have an `applicationIdSuffix` which allows me to install the play-store version and the current development version in parallel on the same device. This all worked fine until I added the wear app.

The main app`s `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        applicationId "com.example.mainApp"
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'                
        }
        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix '.beta'
        }
        release {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

The Wear-App has the same build types with the same applicationIdSuffix values. However, when I build the beta app (by calling `gradle assembleBeta`) the build process builds `:wear:assembleRelease` instead of `:wear:assembleBeta` which is why I get the following error message during build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:handleBetaMicroApk'.
> The main and the micro apps do not have the same package name.
```

How can I tell the build process to build the correct build type when packaging the main app with build type `beta`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following the link posted by Scott Barta (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication) I came up with this :

In the build.gradle of the wear app, add `publishNonDefault true` (to publish all variants):

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

In the build.gradle of the main app,
Replace

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

By

```
debugWearApp project(path:':wear', configuration: 'debug')
releaseWearApp project(path:':wear', configuration: 'release')
```

Comment: How to combine this with flavors?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0. The dependency mechanism has changed and also flavours don't play well with this either

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want; the build variant of a module isn't propagated to the builds of dependent modules on build. This is tracked in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962

There's a facility to make one module depend on a specific variant of another one, as documented in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication, but I don't think this mechanism can be extended to do differential packaging of Wear apps.

Comment: I tried the mechanism described in your second link but it doesn't work for ware apps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link tracking this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
Now there is official support for build variants (see answer of *[Cyril Leroux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141039/wear-app-and-with-custom-build-type-with-applicationidsuffix#answer-29142423)*). Hence this answer is deprecated.

---

I found a very (very) ugly solution which has some drawbacks but works for now until there is support for build variants for wear apps.

I set a global variable in the rootProject which contains the `applicationIdSuffix` of the currently built main app.

Within `build.gradle` of the **main** app I added the following:

```
// Set a global variable, depending on the currently built build-type.
// This allows us to set the applicationIdSuffix of the wear app depending on
// the build-type of the main app.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def task = variant.checkManifest
    def suffix = variant.buildType.applicationIdSuffix
    task.doLast {
        rootProject.ext.currentApplicationIdSuffix = suffix
    }
}
```

In the `build.gradle`of the **wear** app I added the following snipped:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def task = variant.generateBuildConfig
    task.dependsOn(propagateApplicationIdSuffix)
}


task propagateApplicationIdSuffix << {
    project.android.buildTypes.all { type ->
        if (rootProject.hasProperty('currentApplicationIdSuffix')) {
            type.applicationIdSuffix = rootProject.ext.currentApplicationIdSuffix
        }
    }
}
```

This has several drawbacks:

1. You can't build multiple variants (i.e. `gradle assembleBeta assembleRelease`) because the wear app is only built once and hence the second build type fails
2. `gradle check` fails because of reason 1
3. The wear app is still built with build type `release` but the package name is just changed according to to application id suffix of the main app

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you CAN do what you want to do.  I just did it for the enterprise app I work on.

The key is NOT to use wearApp project(':wear'), since that only works when you have the same applicationId in your wear app as your main app.  And let's face it, how often in real life does that situation happen?  If it happens, you probably aren't using Gradle to the best of it's ability.

You want to follow the instructions for Package Manually in the google wear docs 
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually

Unfortunately, this will require you to build your wear app with the same applicationId as the particular build variant you are making at the time, but it does allow you to successfully package the wear app inside an app with multiple applicationId.

Also, one trick I do that helps is to not put the wear apk inside /res/raw, but in /assets, that way you don't have to deal with Andriod Studio compressing the apk.

Hope this helps!  Drove me crazy for a couple days finding a solution.  And the only tutorial out there is in French, and I had to translate the website to read it!
https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.octo.com%2Fpackager-une-application-android-wear-dans-la-vraie-vie%2F