# Android wear project with 3 flavors, 3 buildTypes and 2 applicationIdSuffixes

Tags: android, build.gradle, wear-os, android-productflavors, android-build-type

When I build my project after trying to combine wearApp flavors and buildTypes with applicationIdSuffixes, i get the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:handleFirstCustomerTestMicroApk'.
> The main and the micro apps do not have the same package name.
```

From my app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        debuggable true
        embedMicroApp = true
    }
    customerTest {
        applicationIdSuffix '.customertest'
        debuggable true
        embedMicroApp = true
    }
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        minifyEnabled true
        embedMicroApp = true
    }
}

productFlavors {
    first {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.first'
    }
    second {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.second'
    }
    third {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.third'
    }
}

dependencies {
    firstWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstDebug')
    firstWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstCustomerTest')
    firstWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstRelease')

    secondWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondDebug')
    secondWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondCustomerTest')
    secondWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondRelease')

    thirdWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdDebug')
    thirdWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdCustomerTest')
    thirdWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdRelease')
}
```

From my wear/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    customerTest {
        applicationIdSuffix '.customertest'
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    first {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.first'
    }
    second {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.second'
    }
    third {
        applicationId 'com.my.app.third'
    }
}

android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

I know from these that `<buildType>WearApp` is possible, but what I really need is `<flavor><BuildType>WearApp` (which don't seem to be possible right now):

- [Android wear application packaging fails with flavours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27387429/3328701)
- [Wear App and with custom build type with applicationIdSuffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25141039/3328701)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74658

Keeping all the above 9 wearApp dependencies sort of works if I remove the applicationIdSuffixes, but then it still builds one wear apk per buildType no matter what buildType I choose in Android Studio - and I really need the applicationIdSuffixes.

Anyone have a workaround for this? As of today I'm adding and removing wearApp dependencies manually every time I need to change my buildType and / or flavor, and it's not exactly a solution I'm comfortable with in the long run.

EDIT: I didn't notice this at first, but for some reason variants firstDebug, secondDebug and thirdDebug builds just fine with all 9 wearApp dependencies in build.gradle. The error message remains the same for firstCustomerTest, firstRelease, secondCustomerTest, secondRelease, thirdCustomerTest and thirdRelease though. All variants compile the 9 wearApps every time, would be neat to reduce this to 1.

Comment: Not related to your question: define "initwith debug" in buildTypes-customerTest, so your custom buildtype will use all settings from 'debug' automatically. Now you only need to define 'applicationIdSuffix': the only different compared to 'debug'
See dev.android.com for reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types
... I'm aware it's not incredibly useful in your case, but I'd still like to point out the possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [This Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/kKZpiXbOW7k)

Try this

```
configurations {
    firstDebugWearApp
    firstCustomerTestWearApp
    firstReleaseWearApp
    secondDebugWearApp
 ...//  And all the others
}
  dependencies {
        firstDebugWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstDebug')
        firstCustomerTestWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstCustomerTest')
        firstReleaseWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'firstRelease')

        secondDebugWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondDebug')
        secondCustomerTestWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondCustomerTest')
        secondReleaseWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'secondRelease')

        thirdDebugWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdDebug')
        thirdCustomerTestWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdCustomerTest')
        thirdReleaseWearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'thirdRelease')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, 'configurations' was the missing link! It still builds all of them on each build, but the important thing is that it's working.